# Creating External data field using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom

I need to create different types of fields using CSOM in a list. I got stuck with the External data field. So I wanted to ask, is it possible to create external data field in a list using CSOM?

Comment: Custom development with C#?

Comment: Yes custom development

Answer (score 2):

yes, It is possible to create external data field in a list using CSOM.

```
<Field
       ID="{3F1AAE19-964D-4B0C-B200-F0011FA97126}"
       Name="DescriptionTitle" Hidden="FALSE" StaticName="DescriptionTitle"
       DisplayName="Description Title" Type="Text" Required="FALSE" Group="Test">
  </Field>
<Field
     ID="{5C0E78EB-5D22-4D88-82DD-CB5C14496BAD}"
     Name="Icon" Hidden="FALSE" StaticName="Icon"
     DisplayName="Icon" Type="Image" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="ThemeHtml" Required="FALSE" Group="Test">
  </Field>
  <Field
    ID="{80C6CE62-BB42-419C-BF00-B7B60108CF61}"
    Name="CalendarContent" DisplayName="Calendar Content"
    Hidden="FALSE" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" StaticName="CalendarContent"
    Type="HTML" Required="False" Group="Test">
  </Field>
```

[Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx) for Reference URL.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can very well update external data column using CSOM. Please refer below link-

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushalendra/2012/04/01/updating-external-data-column-using-client-object-model/

For creating columns/field, please refer - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231593.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I case anyone needs to create external columns again. The below code worked perfectly for me. In my case the external field was pointing to a WCF service.

```
context.Load(web);
context.ExecuteQuery();
string businessFieldSchema = "<Field Type='BusinessData' DisplayName='Display name here' Required='FALSE' EnforceUniqueValues='FALSE' " +
                "SystemInstance='System Instance as on BCS here' EntityNamespace='Namespace as on BCS' EntityName='Entity name as on BCS' BdcField='Name of the entity field'" +
                " Group='Field Group here' Hidden='FALSE' UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary='FALSE' " +
                " StaticName='Static Name Here' Name='Name Here'/>";
var businessField = allFields.AddFieldAsXml(businessFieldSchema, false, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
businessField.Update();
context.Load(businessField);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

-Hope it helps